# how to get rid of footers in ACM templates

Tags: acm, acmart

I'm using the ACM LaTeX template for a document with

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
```

and I'm trying to get rid of the lines on the title pages saying

> 2022. XXXX-XXXX/2022/7-ART $15
>       https://doi.org/10.1145/nnnnnnn.nnnnnnn

as well as the footer on every page saying

> . Vol 1, No. 1, Article . Publication date: July 2022.

and I'm completely lost. Can anybody help me in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seems like I figured it out -- answering this in case others with the same question end up here: you can do so by adding `nonacm` like this:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall,nonacm]{acmart}
```